# method getSums in class RowBreaker cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I am trying to create a runner, but this error pops up:

```
method getSums in class RowBreaker cannot be applied to given types;
int[] sums1 = rb1.getSums();
error: method getSums in class RowBreaker cannot be applied to given types;
int[] sums2 = rb2.getSums();
```

Here is the main class code:

```
public class RowBreaker {

    private int[] arr;

    public RowBreaker(int[] GO) {
        arr = GO;
    }

    public int[] getSums(int[] arr){
        int theSum=0;
        int[] sum = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            int n = arr[i];
            while(n!=0){
                if(n%10!=0){
                    sum[i]=theSum;
                }
            }
            n=n/10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

And here is the runner, what seems to be the problem:

```
public class RowBreakerRunner {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int[] one = {36,271,343,2001,1048};
        RowBreaker rb1 = new RowBreaker(one);
        int[] sums1 = rb1.getSums();


        int[] two = {361,2348,174,129,7002};
        RowBreaker rb2 = new RowBreaker(two);
        int[] sums2 = rb2.getSums();
    }
}
```

I have tried google, and I do not have any friends that I can ask. Any help is appreciated! I am still new to coding concepts.

Comment: `getSums()` takes an `int[]` parameter. But you are not providing that when you call the method.

Comment: put argument to your method ` rb1.getSums(one);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `int[] sums1 = rb1.getSums();` and `int[] sums2 = rb2.getSums();` you have an `int[]` as your parameter so you have to pass something in. I suggest you remove the parameter from your method `getSums` and just use the `private int[] arr` instance you already have.

**EDIT**

Here's an idea of what your classes should look like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RowBreakerRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] one = { 36, 271, 343, 2001, 1048 };
        RowBreaker rb1 = new RowBreaker(one);
        int[] sums1 = rb1.getSums();

        int[] two = { 361, 2348, 174, 129, 7002 };
        RowBreaker rb2 = new RowBreaker(two);
        int[] sums2 = rb2.getSums();

        Arrays.stream(sums1).forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));
        Arrays.stream(sums2).forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));

    }
}

public class RowBreaker {

    private int[] arr;

    public RowBreaker(int[] GO) {
        arr = GO;
    }

    public int[] getSums() {
        int theSum = 0;
        int[] sum = new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int n = arr[i];
            while (n != 0) {
                if (n % 10 != 0) {
                    sum[i] = theSum;
                }
            }
            n = n / 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**Note:** The code seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Make sure to make the RowBreaker class public again.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `getSums` with a parameter `int[] arr`, yet you try to call it with no parameters: `int[] sums1 = rb1.getSums();`

If you meant to use the private class member `arr`, just remove the parameter from the function declaration:

```
public int[] getSums() {...
```

On the other hand, if you wish to pass an array to the method `getSums`, you need to explicitely do so:

```
int[] sums1 = rb1.getSums(one);
```